# LINQ statement to retrieve only circular referenced (or parent) records?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, silverlight

### SQL TABLE COLUMNS

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CountrySubdivision]
(
    [CountrySubdivisionCode] [VARCHAR]( 10 ) NOT NULL,
        
    [CountryCode] AS
    (
        CONVERT( [CHAR]( 2 ), LEFT( [CountrySubdivisionCode], ( 2 )), ( 0 ))
    ) 
    PERSISTED,
        
    [SubdivisionCode] AS
    (
        CONVERT( [VARCHAR]( 7 ), SUBSTRING( [CountrySubdivisionCode], CHARINDEX( '-', [CountrySubdivisionCode] ) + ( 1 ), LEN( [CountrySubdivisionCode] ) - CHARINDEX( '-', [CountrySubdivisionCode] )), ( 0 ))
    ) 
    PERSISTED,

    [Name]                   [NVARCHAR]( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    [Category]               [VARCHAR]( 50 )    NOT NULL,
    [ParentSubdivisionCode]  [VARCHAR]( 7 )     NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CountrySubdivision] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ( 
        [CountrySubdivisionCode] ASC 
    )
)
```

### SQL TABLE SAMPLE DATA

```
                                                                      Parent
      Country  Subdivision                                          Subdivision 
 Code   Code      Code     Name                Category                Code
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GB-ENG   GB       ENG      England             country                  NULL
GB-SCT   GB       SCT      Scotland            country                  NULL
GB-WLS   GB       WLS      Wales               country                  NULL
GB-NIR   GB       NIR      Northern Ireland    province                 NULL
GB-BKM   GB       BKM      Buckinghamshire     two-tier county          ENG
GB-CAM   GB       CAM      Cambridgeshire      two-tier county          ENG
GB-CMA   GB       CMA      Cumbria             two-tier county          ENG
GB-SWK   GB       SWK      Southwark           London borough           ENG
GB-STN   GB       STN      Sutton              London borough           ENG
GB-TWH   GB       TWH      Tower Hamlets       London borough           ENG
GB-LDS   GB       LDS      Leeds               metropolitan district    ENG
GB-LIV   GB       LIV      Liverpool           metropolitan district    ENG
GB-MAN   GB       MAN      Manchester          metropolitan district    ENG
```

### REQUIREMENT

I need a result set only consisting of parent records.  So in **LINQ** I was thinking of something like:

```cs
// Get all Subdivisions.
var csData = GetSubdivisions() as ObservableCollection<CountrySubdivisionData>;

// Get all Parent Subdivisions.
var psData = csData.Where
(
    ps => 
    ps.ParentSubdivisionCode.IsNull() && 
    csData.Any
    (
        cs => 
        cs.ParentSubdivisionCode == ps.SubdivisionCode
    )
)
.OrderBy(ps => ps.CountrySubdivisionCode)
.ThenBy(ps => ps.Category)
.ThenBy(ps => ps.Name)
.ToObservableCollection();
```

Just FYI, `IsNull()` is a simple extension method I use:

```cs
public static bool IsNull(this object obj)
{
    return obj == null;
}
```

### QUESTION

Is there a better LINQ statement than what I have to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks good/readable as it stands. Are you experiencing any problems with it?

Comment: @Chris - Not that I know of, but this isn't out to the testers yet.  I just wanted to be sure it was fully optimized, as I do a lot more than just this filter in my control.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - My objects are created from WCF services.  No frameworks.  Just standard LINQ.

Comment: What does `GetSubdivisions()` do, can you pass the query along to it so the filtered query gets passed to SQL via Linq-to-Entities, Linq-to-SQL, or your own framework? It would be more efficient if you could perform your filtering server side instead of client side like you are currently. **EDIT:** You said you are using WCF services, is there any way to pass a filter (or add a new function to pass a filter) to the WCF? Also have you looked in to using [OData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx) (WCF's sibling)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - `GetSubdivisions()` gets the default collection of all country subdivisions (parents and children) because all items regardless of being a parent or a child are still each a subdivision of their own, hence the circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the only row that should be returned from your given data set is `GB-ENG`.

You shouldn't have to create an intermediary collection. You can use the same collection, like this:

```
var data = items.Where(i1 =>
    i1.ParentSubdivisionCode == null &&
    items.Any(i2 => i2.ParentSubdivisionCode == i1.SubdivisionCode)
)
.OrderBy(i => i.CountrySubdivisionCode)
.ThenBy(i => i.Category)
.ThenBy(i => i.Name)
.ToList();
```

If performance is a concern (and depending your backing data set), you might want to retrieve a collection of `ParentSubdivisionCode` values first to optimize the `Contains` method. This is only valid for LINQ-to-objects.

```
var parentSubdivisionCodes = new HashSet<string>(items.Select(i => i.ParentSubdivisionCode));
var data = items.Where(i => 
    i.ParentSubdivisionCode == null &&
    parentSubdivisionCodes.Contains(i.SubdivisionCode)
)
.OrderBy(ps => ps.CountrySubdivisionCode)
.ThenBy(ps => ps.Category)
.ThenBy(ps => ps.Name)
.ToList();
```

By replacing `items.Any(i2 => i2.ParentSubdivisionCode == i1.SubdivisionCode)` with `parentSubdivisionCodes.Contains(i.SubdivisionCode)`, we removed a nested iteration and leveraged the speed of `HashSet<T>.Contains`.

Here's the whole program I used to test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

    internal class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            #region
            var store = @"
                GB-ENG,   GB,       ENG,      England,             country,                  NULL
                GB-SCT,   GB,       SCT,      Scotland,            country,                  NULL
                GB-WLS,   GB,       WLS,      Wales,               country,                  NULL
                GB-NIR,   GB,       NIR,      Northern Ireland,    province,                 NULL
                GB-BKM,   GB,       BKM,      Buckinghamshire,     two-tier county,          ENG
                GB-CAM,   GB,       CAM,      Cambridgeshire,      two-tier county,          ENG
                GB-CMA,   GB,       CMA,      Cumbria,             two-tier county,          ENG
                GB-SWK,   GB,       SWK,      Southwark,           London borough,           ENG
                GB-STN,   GB,       STN,      Sutton,              London borough,           ENG
                GB-TWH,   GB,       TWH,      Tower Hamlets,       London borough,           ENG
                GB-LDS,   GB,       LDS,      Leeds,               metropolitan district,    ENG
                GB-LIV,   GB,       LIV,      Liverpool,          metropolitan district,     ENG
                GB-MAN,   GB,       MAN,      Manchester,          metropolitan district,    ENG
            ";

            var items = store
                .Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(line => line.Trim())
                .Where(line => line != string.Empty)
                .Select(line => line
                    .Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(item => item.Trim())
                    .Where(item => item != string.Empty)
                    .ToArray()
                )
                .Select(item => new {
                    Code = item[0],
                    CountrySubdivisionCode = item[1],
                    SubdivisionCode = item[2],
                    Name = item[3],
                    Category = item[4],
                    ParentSubdivisionCode = item[5] == "NULL" ? default(string) : item[5]
                })
                .ToList();
            #endregion

            #region
            Console.WriteLine();
            items.Where(i1 =>
                i1.ParentSubdivisionCode == null &&
                items.Any(i2 => i2.ParentSubdivisionCode == i1.SubdivisionCode)
            )
            .OrderBy(i => i.CountrySubdivisionCode)
            .ThenBy(i => i.Category)
            .ThenBy(i => i.Name)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Code));
            #endregion

            #region
            Console.WriteLine();
            var parentSubdivisionCodes = new HashSet<string>(items.Select(i => i.ParentSubdivisionCode));
            items.Where(i => 
                i.ParentSubdivisionCode == null &&
                parentSubdivisionCodes.Contains(i.SubdivisionCode)
            )
            .OrderBy(ps => ps.CountrySubdivisionCode)
            .ThenBy(ps => ps.Category)
            .ThenBy(ps => ps.Name)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Code));
            #endregion

            #region
            Console.WriteLine();
            var csData = items;
            csData.Where(ps =>
                ps.ParentSubdivisionCode == null &&
                csData.Any(cs =>
                    cs.ParentSubdivisionCode == ps.SubdivisionCode
                )
            )
            .OrderBy(ps => ps.CountrySubdivisionCode)
            .ThenBy(ps => ps.Category)
            .ThenBy(ps => ps.Name)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Code));
            #endregion

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```